# Why does TypeScript code using optional properties in an interface fail to enforce type constraints correctly?

Tags: typescript

I'm encountering an issue with TypeScript when using an interface with optional properties and trying to enforce type constraints using mapped types. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

type KeysOfType<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

const x: KeysOfType<Foo, string> = "a"; // This is valid
const y: KeysOfType<Foo, string> = "b"; // This is invalid
const z: KeysOfType<Foo, number> = "b"; // This is valid
```

This works as expected. The problem arise if i set the properties `a`, `b` or `c` is declared as optional: all constraint fails.

What do I need to change to make mapped type work with this interface? and why?

```js
interface Foo {
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
  c?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `KeysOfType<Foo, string | undefined>` if you make `a` optional?  Since `string | undefined` does not extend `string`.  There are some quirks with your definition of `KeysOfType` that would allow `undefined` itself as a key, but right now your big problem is that you've left `undefined` out of the value type. Does that fix it for you or am I missing something?